# Lambda function to store JSON attribute in DynamoDB using Boto

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

I am working on a python script that will store JSON attributes like ("region","ebs_volume_size","instance_type")inside a dynamodb table using a lambda function
This my lambda function which is taking an input from my python function for the policy

```
import boto3
import time
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
from template_utils import create_aws_iam_policy_template 
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
lambd = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(**event)
  return template_json

table =dynamodb.create_table(
    TableName='GoodTable',
    AttributeDefinitions=[
    {
      "AttributeName": "Content",
      "AttributeType": "S"
    }
    ],
      KeySchema=[
    {
      "AttributeName": "Content",
      "KeyType": "HASH"
    }
  ],
  ProvisionedThroughput={
    "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
    "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
  }
)
time.sleep(20)
table = dynamodb.Table('GoodTable')
response = table.put_item(
    Item= {
        'Content': 'Volume Size', 
        'Details': kwargs.get('ebs_volume_size'),
    }
)
response = table.put_item(
    Item= {
        'Content': 'Instance Type', 
        'Details': kwargs.get('instance_type'),
    }
)
response = table.put_item(
    Item= {
        'Content': 'Region', 
        'Details': kwargs.get('region'),
    }
)
```

This my python function "template_utils.py":

```
   import json
    import meta_templates
    from jinja2 import Template
    
    start_time_1 = input("What's the start time")
    end_time1 = input("What's the end time")
    def create_aws_iam_policy_template(**kwargs):
      template_data = {}
      template_data["region"] = kwargs.get('region')
      template_data["start_time"] = kwargs.get('end_time')
      template_data["end_time"] = kwargs.get('start_time')
      template_data["instance_types"] = kwargs.get('instance_type')
      template_data["ebs_volume_size"] = kwargs.get('ebs_volume_size')
      template_data["meta_template_name"] = kwargs.get('meta_template_name')
    
      meta_template_dict = getattr(meta_templates, template_data["meta_template_name"])
      meta_template_json = json.dumps(meta_template_dict)
      template_json = Template(meta_template_json).render(template_data)
      return template_json  
    
    
    template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(
      region="us-east-2",
      instance_type="t2.micro",
      ebs_volume_size="20",
      meta_template_name="ec2_policy_meta_template",
      start_time = start_time_1,
      end_time = end_time1
    )
    
    
    print(template_json)

This is my IAM policy:
ec2_policy_meta_template = { 
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": "ec2:RunInstances",
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                    "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::image/ami-*"
                ],
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:NumericLessThanEquals": {
                        "ec2:VolumeSize": "{{ebs_volume_size}}"
                    },
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor1",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:TerminateInstances",
                    "ec2:StopInstances"
                ],
                "Resource": "arn:aws:ec2:{{region}}::instance/*",
                "Condition": {
                    "ForAllValues:StringEquals": {
                        "ec2:InstanceType": "{{instance_type}}"
                    }
                }
            },
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor2",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "ec2:Describe*",
                    "ec2:GetConsole*",
                    "ec2:CreateKeyPair"
                ],
                "Resource": "*",
                "Condition": {
                    "DateGreaterThan": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{start_time}}"
                    },
                    "DateLessThanEquals": {
                        "aws:CurrentTime": "{{end_time}}"
                    }
                }
            }
        ]
    }
```

I don't want to use "f-strings" rather just the values from the python function, I am getting an error "undefined variable'kwargs'".

Comment: Your indentation is wrong in your lambda. `dynamodb.create_table` will never run. Also where do `ebs_volume_size` is supposed to come from? Is it input to your lambda function?

Comment: "ebs_volume_size" will come from "template_json"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **indentation** and **kwargs** should be fixed in the corrected version of the code below. Also make sure that you provide correct permissions in **lambda execution role** so that it has permissions to access dynamodb.

```
import boto3
import time
import json
import meta_templates
from jinja2 import Template
from template_utils import create_aws_iam_policy_template 

dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')
lambd = boto3.client('lambda')

def lambda_handler(event, context):
  template_json = create_aws_iam_policy_template(**event)
  
  table = dynamodb.create_table(
      TableName='GoodTable',
      AttributeDefinitions=[
      {
        "AttributeName": "Content",
        "AttributeType": "S"
      }
      ],
        KeySchema=[
      {
        "AttributeName": "Content",
        "KeyType": "HASH"
      }
    ],
    ProvisionedThroughput={
      "ReadCapacityUnits": 1,
      "WriteCapacityUnits": 1
    }
  )
  time.sleep(20)
  table = dynamodb.Table('GoodTable')
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Volume Size', 
          'Details': template_json.get('ebs_volume_size'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Instance Type', 
          'Details': template_json.get('instance_type'),
      }
  )
  response = table.put_item(
      Item= {
          'Content': 'Region', 
          'Details': template_json.get('region'),
      }
  )
```

Comment: I have given Lambda permission to my Dynamo but even after that while running the lambda function, I am not able to create a dynamodb table any ideas on what might be going wrong?

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar Your function creates the table. When you invoke it second time, creation will fail as you can't have two tables of the same name.

Comment: Shouldn't it atleast create the table once while running this program, I got no error just the output in dict form

Comment: @PranaySinghParihar It should. Check CloudWatch logs for errors. You can make new question with details of the errors and the issue.